# Низкоуровневая графика

Tags: linux, c, графика

Изучаю C, хотел бы поработать с закрашиванием пикселей без библиотек наподобие opengl и т.д. Пишу под Linux, хотелось бы иметь базовые функции наподобие `set_pixel(x, y, struct rgb)`. Дает ли linux такой api? Если нет, то как работает `opengl`, как он выводит что-либо, какие функции для этого вызывает?

Если есть пример реализации на C, прошу.

Comment: Сам linux не даёт графического api, и какого-то единого set_pixel не существует

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Стек графических технологий в GNU/Linux системах довольно разнообразен и содержит значительное множество технологий, которыми можно воспользоваться. Выбирать какую-либо одну за вопрошающего считается дурным тоном, так что я ограничусь их общим (но не исчерпывающим) описанием и перечислением.

### Непосредственно в Linux

Для графики *непосредственно в ядре Linux* есть два с половиной API:

- *Фреймбуфер* (`/deb/fb0`)
- [DRI/DRM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Infrastructure) (*Direct rendering Infrastructure*/*Management*) (/dev/dri/*)
- Прочие старые специфичные драйвера видеокарт.

Причём два последних предоставляют несколько различный интерфейс для конкретных устройств и интересны только для создания «драйверов» пространства пользователя (`libdrm_{intel,nouveau,radeon...}`/`xserver-xorg-video-{intel,nvidia,radeon,...}`), но не для конечных приложений.

#### Фреймбуфер

Старый добрый интерфейс, похож на манипуляцию с видеопамятью в ДОС-стиле. На большинстве современных систем будет работать только в «настоящей» консоли (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>). Суть в том, что открывается устройство `/dev/fb0` и рисование ведётся вручную попиксельно напрямую в кадр через обычные системные вызовы `write` или `mmap`. [Простой пример](https://github.com/BartekLew/fblib/blob/fb-example/fbgrad.c) из гугла.

Это самый простой и низкоуровневый вариант, если есть желание поработать именно с пиксельной графикой и как можно ближе к ядру без каких-либо прослоек, я бы рекомендовал именно его, но чисто в ознакомительных целях. На практике сегодня используется редко, разве что в каких-то сверхлёгких встраиваемых системах для которых полноценный X-сервер — перебор.

### Низкоуровневые API

Основные в этой категории:

- Интерфейс DRM — унифицированный интерфейс библиотек (libdrm) для доступа к системным вызовам DRI. Основное предназначение — абстрагироваться от разности в реализациях видеокарт/драйверов конкретных производителей. Интересен в основном разработчикам других API.
- X API (в том числе через xlib/xcb) предоставляет в первую очередь средства управления окнами, но в том числе и простого рисования в них из серии «[нарисовать](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/drawing/) линию, дугу, прямоугольник» и «нарисовать пиксель». Но по факту сейчас эти вызовы практически не используются, а большинство приложений рисует всё во внутренний pixmap, а затем целиком его отрисовывает.
- Различные API 3d-графики, основные — [OpenGL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) и [Vulkan](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulkan_(API)). Прежде всего предназначены для сложной обработки (в том числе 3d) графики, но так или иначе при желании позволяют работать с отдельными пикселями.

### Высокоуровневые библиотеки

- Различные графические тулкиты: tk, gtk, Qt, wxWidgets. Основное назначение этих библиотек — отображение элементов графического интерфейса (кнопочек, текстовых полей итп), но они также почти всегда содержат некие примитивы для простого рисования.
- Различные высокоуровневые графические библиотеки. Большинство являются надстройками/абстакциями над openGL/Vulkan/Framebuffer/X11 и другими. Примеры: sdl, glfw, sfml и др.

### Ответы на конкретные вопросы

> Пишу под Linux, хотелось бы иметь базовые функции наподобие `set_pixel(x, y, struct rgb)`. Дает ли linux такой api?

И да и нет, почти на любом уровне из вышеперечисленных есть возможность использовать подобный интерфейс, но в большинстве случаев он либо не практичен и значительно медленнее «нормальных» инструментов или представляет собой рисование в какой-то промежуточный программный буфер, который затем выводится.

> Если нет, то как работает opengl, как он выводит что-либо, какие функции для этого вызывает?

Если кратко, то на современных открытых драйверах он использует `libdrm`, который через соответствующий интерфейс в `/dev/dri/*` управляет драйвером видеокарты; закрытые драйвера используют свою реализацию openGL, которая напрямую общается драйвером. Изображение при этом рендерится прямо на устройстве по набору «инструкций» переданных через вызовы openGL, а затем помещается в конкретную область экрана, «окно». При этом обычно готовое изображение не покидает графический адаптер. Есть и программная реализация (`libGL-mesa-swx11`), которая фактически эмулирует эту работу на обычном CPU, но не даёт пользователю никакого дополнительного контроля. Само собой обычно она в разы медленнее.

Comment: Вопрос по произодительности, что будет производительней, opengl или вывод в фреймбуфер? Именно для 2d графики, спасибо.

Comment: @АлександрПупкин, просто голый вывод заранее подготовленной картинки, на современном оборудовании, — примерно одинаково — обе операции по ресурсам пренебрежимо малы... но вот какая-либо отрисовка на GL (опять же на подходящем оборудовании и подходящими методами) будет значительно быстрее...

Answer (score 1):

Если вас интересуют именно реализации геометрических алгоритмов, рассмотрите запись в растровый графический файл вместо записи на экран - это не так сложно.

В [данной статье](https://habr.com/ru/post/248153/) приводится небольшой фрагмент кода для записи в формат `TGA`

```
#include "tgaimage.h"

const TGAColor white = TGAColor(255, 255, 255, 255);
const TGAColor red   = TGAColor(255, 0,   0,   255);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        TGAImage image(100, 100, TGAImage::RGB);
        image.set(52, 41, red);
        image.flip_vertically(); // i want to have the origin at the left bottom corner of the image
        image.write_tga_file("output.tga");
        return 0;
}
```

[github с полным кодом](https://github.com/ssloy/tinyrenderer/tree/909fe20934ba5334144d2c748805690a1fa4c89f)

Comment: Читал статью, библиотека написана на C++, хотя там 300+ строк кода, отличная идея переписать под C, займусь, спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Одно из **принципиальных** отличий виды от люниха заключается в том, что винда **позволяет** приложению писать в системную память (видеобуфер) а люних - **не позволяет**

Это приводит к тому, что винда падает от "неправильных" графических приложений, а люних - нет. Всё, что может сделать неадекватный программист - уронить Х-сервер. Ядро при этом не пострадает.

Но за это приходится платить тем, что в винде графические игрушки работает быстро, а в люнихе - медленно.

Так что никакой функции для записи точки в видеопамять в люнихе нет.

Comment: Но ведь X-сервер это приложение, которое как-то пишет?

Comment: @andreymal Да, приложение. Как и любое другое приложение, выполняет файловые операции (а монитор - это файл), через вызовы функций ядра ОС.